# How to add a ion-header-bar with reduced height

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to add ion-header-bar and I want to reduce the height of the header - bar. The problem is that ion-content which is below the header bar doesn't get placed properly. Because I have reduced the height of header bar, the ion content is far way below the header - bar. How to place the ion-content so that it doesnt occupy the extra space that i have reduced for header-bar.

Comment: Can you please share screen-shot, to get better understanding

Comment: I am sorry . I dont have any option to post the image. My question here is, How to insert ion-header-bar between ion-view and ion-content so that ion-content is exactly below the ion-header bar. 
Note: I am trying to place ion-header bar with reduced height. 
Problem : If i place ion-header without reducing the height , everything is fine.But if i reduce the height, there is a gap between header-bar and content.
How do i avoid this gap so that ion-content gets placed properly below the header.

Comment: Share the code you used to reduce the height of ion-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the height of the header by overriding Ionic sass variables from `src/theme/variables.scss` file.

Add the below variables to the `variables.scss` file to override the default height of 56px:

```
$toolbar-md-height:  40px;
$toolbar-ios-height: 40px;
```

More details here: [Official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/)